# In TypeScript, how to invalidate truth assertion after asynchronous operation?

Tags: typescript

The code is as follows:

```
function delay(ms: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const obj: { a?: () => any } = {
  a: () => {},
};

async function test() {
    if (obj.a) { 
        await delay(1000);
        obj.a() // want an obj.a may be undefined error
        delete obj.a
    }
}

test()
test() // TypeError: obj.a is not a function
```

I remember that TypeScript supported this feature a long time ago. I'm not sure whether it is still available now?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already checking `if (obj.a)`, TypeScript will not complain that `obj.a` can be undefined.

What are you trying to achieve by the way? Usually the usage of delete is not really recommended, there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) bug:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYBsCGBPAFAWwGcAuRMEfAI1QCcBKRAbwChFEbUoQakxUB3RAAUacfDEKpcuDoTjoAbqgYBeAHyJJUACox8qOCCgzUcxagA0iInToBuZgF9mzCAkJREcSgCtSjREwAflJcVQ1MMGxER0QVJlZA0PCmRwsnB2ZMQmxIRFBIWAREKFNjBhY2GGBEXG8fADpMCsREtkx+TBhPNCw8AEYABmH7Nq9fJrDEAHppxE6wT0jxxsxrHERqRHA0YBg+ZERaURox3s5UFabE52dmUo8w+7Kp2cRtbAAHVABRGhPSPUmogJGQ4Et8uBoPAwEA)

```ts
async function test() {
  if (obj.a) { 
    await delay(1000);
    obj.a() // want an obj.a may be undefined error
    delete obj.a
  }
}
```

A better way to write it is not to check at all, but to only invoke `obj.a` if it exists using the [Optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYBsCGBPAFAWwGcAuRMEfAI1QCcBKRAbwChFEbUoQakxUB3RAAUacfDEKpcuDoTjoAbqgYBeAHyJJUACox8qOCCgzUcxagA0iInToBuZgF9mzCAkJREcSgCtSjREwAflJcVQ1MMGxER0QVJlZA0PCmRwsnB2ZMQmxIRFBIWAREKFNjBhY2TH5MGE80LDwARgAGNvtE7x8AOmDusMQAekHEAAc4QkIYSnRo8DRgGD5kK0ojLzBZxCWFOABrVG3gRFQADwkoQkSGzkOu3qcXUo8w5mfyoZH9oA)

```ts
async function test() {
  await delay(1000);
  obj.a?.() // possibly undefined, but only invoke if exists
  delete obj.a
}
```

Comment: I know this, but it's a runtime check, but what I want is a static check

Comment: There is no such thing as compile-time only check which doesn’t affect runtime code. All type guards have runtime functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered!

I've had type warnings on setTimeout before, so I thought it was ts checking all async methods.

I just learned today that ts is for all callback methods：

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=5&pln=16&pc=113#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAXDA3jAhgflQCgEoYBeAPizAE8YBfE9AKBi3yLPRoBoGaBuBhgDMArmGBQAluAqUAYqOB5gmADYr4mYAGtWJcpipE0TZjGVqN2wjwETBMPAkQA6TEZPMnr6x5gQAplAAKhIAtv4gwlB4hHqMpglwSN4EvjSpvgD0mTAAkrBQwgBOkHBRMFAAFpiwqipmdZZaMOFVIAAmEDAA5oFYFZQADv4wAO6YJRJg3ZxjlRLAlXkVlZHdlbDjXZgwgv41xSMg9pgQlGItgaudvgZyCjFs5MaJpl6Y1gnpNkA)